# Cannot Start mlflow ui on google cloud platform virtual machine instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mlflow

after running mlflow ui on command line
and  clicking http://127.0.0.1:5000/
i get site cannot be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

I have already updated firewall rules on VPC network in GCP and on my local machine and activated the ports

> This site can’t be reached127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
>
> Try:
>
> - Checking the connection
> - Checking the proxy and the firewall
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to your MlFlow UI by using the IP address of your Google Cloud VM instead of 127.0.0.1, which is equal to localhost, meaning it is only available inside the Google Cloud VM.